# Error message with qqnorm

Tags: r, nlme

I have used the `lme` function in the `nlme` package to create a linear mixed effects model of data from a two-factor biological experiment, where both factors are categorical:

```
model<-lme(responsevariable~factor1*factor2, data=dataset)
```

I am trying to plot a quantile-quantile plot of this model to assess normality prior to performing an ANOVA on this model.

I have tried to use the `qqnorm` function:

```
qqnorm(model)
```

However, on executing the above command, I get the following error message:

> "no applicable method for "xyplot" applied to an object of class
>   "c("double", "numeric")""

I am looking for suggestions as to what this error means, if there is way to resolve it in order to get `qqnorm` to work on my model, or if not, what other functions could be used in R to create a quantile-quantile plot of my model.